# NHibernate: Generate mappings for stored procedures

Tags: .net, nhibernate, orm

I need to call some stored procedures via NHibernate (not necessarily for CRUD-operations). Is there a freeware/open source tool which can generate mappings (a hbm.xml) for stored procedures and tables?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NHibernate Generators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41752/nhibernate-generators)

Comment: A Google search shows this question has been asked quite a few times already: http://www.google.com/#q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+nhibernate+code+generator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by mapping the stored procedures as named queries. There is a good write up on this at [NHForge.org](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/04/17/nhibernate-mapping-named-queries-lt-query-gt-and-lt-sql-query-gt.aspx). You can create the stored procedures themselves as part of your schema generation using database-object mappings; see [here](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/16/nhibernate-mapping-ltdatabase-objectgt.aspx) for details.

As far as some sort of pre-built tool goes to accomplish this, you're pretty much out of luck. However, implementing this as described above is trivial.